# Question related to Fermat curve: Does the equation $A x^n + By^n = C z^n$ have any solution in $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A, B, C \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $\gcd(A,B,C)=1$. Is it known if the equation $A x^n + By^n = C z^n$ has any non-trivial solutions $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$? I know there are no such solutions if $A = B = C =1$, because this is Fermat's last theorem. I was just wondering if something similar was known when there are positive coefficients as well or not. Thank you very much!

PS By non-trivial solutions I mean the solutions that do not arise from degenerate cases.

Comment: You need to exclude some other degenerate cases to make the question interesting: for example, if $x = y = z$ and $A+B = C$, there will be a solution.

Comment: ... or $z=1$ and $C=Ax^n+By^n$ ...

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the question to avoid these degenerate cases.

Comment: You can choose any $x,y,z$ so that $(x,y,z) = 1$, and then pick $A,B,C$ so that $Ax^n + By^n = Cz^n$.

Comment: Maybe the question is not perfectly stated, but I think it is clear that it asks about what is known about other diophantine equations $Ax^n+By^n=Cz^n$ where $A, B, C, n$ are given , and $x,y,z$ are the unknowns.

Comment: The right question seems to be whether, for any given $A,B,C \in \mathbb{Z}$ (not all zero), the equation $Ax^n + By^n = Cz^n$ has only finitely many solutions $(x,y,z;n)$ with $\mathrm{gcd}(x,y,z) = 1$ and $n > 3$. This follows from the $abc$-conjecture.

Comment: In the case $A = B = 1, C= 2^r$, this has been proved in work of Ribet and Darmon-Merel.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson One can choose positive $x,y,z$ first, and then standard number theory gives $A,B,C \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Then it seems to me that moving terms from one side of the equation to the other as necessary can get to an equivalent equation with all positive terms.

Comment: Yes,thanks. I saw Igor Rivin's answer too.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a slight extension of Matt Young's comment and Geoff Robinson's question: given any relatively prime $x, y$ any sufficiently large $X$ can be written as a positive linear combination of $x^n$ and $y^n$ (how large is "[the Frobenius problem"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNumber.html)). In particular, for any fixed $z,$ you can find a $C>0$ such that $A x^n + By^n = Cz^n,$ for some $A, B> 0.$ Of course, since the OP does not define what "non-trivial" means, this might not be what he wants.